# Firebase Function receive data and sum from different path

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm new in firebase function.I'm want to implement a function that can sum a value from a different path. Here is firebase real-time database structure.

```
sensor:{
  sensor-1: 1
  sensor-2: 1
  sensor-3: 1
  sensor-4: 1
  sum: 4  
 }
```

I want function js that can sum sensor 1-4 value and write it on "sum:". that my start

```
    exports.sumsensor = functions.database.ref('sensor/{id}').onWrite((change)=>{ 
         //compute code in here
         return admin.database().ref('sensor/sum').set('total');
    });
```

how can I implement this. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change your database structure a bit:

```
sensor : {
    sensor-1: 1
    sensor-2: 1
    sensor-3: 1
    sensor-4: 1
}

sensorSum : 4
```

Here is the cloud function code:

```
exports.sumsensor = functions.database.ref('sensor/{id}').onWrite((change,context)=>{ 
     let val = +change.after.val()
     //compute code in here
     return admin.database().ref().child('sensorSum').transaction(function(currentTotal) {
         return currentTotal + val;
     });
});
```

Here is the reference link: [firebase transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction)